# Securing Android App Activity

Tags: android, security

I created an android app and I want to add some security protection to the settings menu (and possibly other activities as well). Specifically I want to use a password to protect access to the settings activity so that when the user clicks on the settings button they have to enter a password to see and change the current settings. Does android offer a built in way to do this? An alternative I devised would be to use another activity to provide a password screen: when the user clicks the settings button in the menu it launches an activity with a text field into which the user enters a password. When the correct password is entered an intent is used to launch the actual settings activity. Would that offer any real security?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a built-in way, I believe the approach you mentioned is reasonable. 
Of course, your user could modify/hack your app to open the settings screen without knowing the password.

If there is any information that is sensitive, you should encrypt it with the password, so that it can only be decrypted if the password is known. Either your information is encrypted and needs a password, or it is there and can be extracted, regardless of the implementation of any screen lock.

The library [PasscodeLock-Android](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/PasscodeLock-Android) seems to do what you want, but only for the entire app, if I am not mistaken. Maybe it can help you with the implementation.

Comment: This is a good answer, I just wanted to emphasize more that it depends on what you want to protect against. You cannot prevent a user from decompiling your apk and change it to not require a password. Anything you give to the user is controlled by the user and you cannot trust it anymore. So while realistically this solution may be good enough, theoretically it is not. A malicious user having physical access to the phone could (at least in theory, but also in practice) just change the app. It is not straightforward, but not impossible either.

Comment: @Zackline thanks for the reply and the link, that seems like it could help. I will poke around with and see if it meets my needs.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Thanks for your contribution to my question. To address the point you raised: Im trying to protect against someone seeing/changing the user's settings choice such as if they borrow the user's phone. Im not trying to protect stored data and Im not trying to restrict access to the entire app, just to the settings menu specifically to view the preference objects.

Comment: @Zackline Also Im not trying to block the user's access to any aspect of the app. The user would set the password needed to access and change the settings menu. Based on what I have also said in my reply to GaborLengyel above you should have a better idea of what Im trying to accomplish. Things like decompilation and messing with the .apk file are beyond the scope of what Im trying to guard against